Replace front half of sillcock
I have this sillcock:

Recently I turned it on and noticed it was spraying water from what seemed like a pinhole in the valve. I was able to unscrew the front of the valve and it seems like the front part body has cracked along a seem. Here are the two parts:

I thought I could just replace the front part, but multiple plumbing supply places don't seem to carry anything that fits. It doesn't seem to be normal 3/4" IP threads - they are very close to the right size but they won't thread on.
Can anyone tell me what the front part of this is called or what kind of threads they might be so I can find a replacement or an adapter or similar?
------ EDIT ------
Upon further investigation, it's not frost-free! (which is great for replacing this, but bad because I winterized it incorrectly). It's a new-construction house (2022) in climate zone 5 (Massachusetts) - am I crazy to have assumed it would be frost-free?


Usually stuff like that it is as cheap or cheaper to buy the whole piece than parts like that.

@crip659, while there might be little difference in price, I am fully sympathetic with OP not wanting to muck about behind that wall, possibly soldering on a new valve, if a replacement for the part can be found.

Though it would not save any money, I'd look for that identical valve and use the outer part as a replacement. That avoids having to work inside the wall cavity, possibly soldering in a replacement valve.
As you state, finding that valve might be difficult, but with the broken part in hand, you should be able to check for compatibility at a plumbing supply or hardware store.
There are some measurements that could help you find a part online:

Check the thread pitch with a gauge (online, they're advertised for less than US$10, or use one at a hardware store, or borrow one).
Check the inside diameter of the damaged part.

BTW, here are two likely cause of valve damage:

Water expands to ice, in colder climates. Before winter, shut off the water inside, before that valve, and drain it, or cover the outside valve with insulation suitable for your climate.
Over-tightening, or tightening a fitting with the wrong tool, can damage it. The best tool to tighten pipe fittings, if clearance allows, is a box-end wrench (ring spanner), or a flare-nut wrench where a box-end wrench cannot be used. Avoid adjustable wrenches!


You still need to be sure the threads match the existing.  The threads will obviously match on a new unit, but they won't necessarily match the existing.

@Huesmann, correct -- which is why it is stated one should shop "with the broken part in hand," meaning one takes the old part to the store, and checks that it fits the base of the new, and why it is stated one should measure the thread pitch and part diameter.

Assuming the packaging permits in-store disassembly.
